# Error message in system.log regarding Undefined variable: block in Filter.php

Tags: magento-1.9, error, filter, rwd-theme, ce-1.9.1.1

Error message is in `system.log` file. Looked at lines 187 and 197 of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` and can't figure out what could be wrong?

Error as displayed in `system.log`:

> 2015-12-29T17:11:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: block  in /home/public_html/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 187
>
> 2015-12-29T17:11:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: block  in /home/public_html/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 197

`Filter.php` file content at line 187 and 197:
[image: Filter.php]

Comment: Howdy! What theme are you using on your site? I found a discussion about this here: http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798%3Ffilter=All+Discussion&page=65/comments?page=497 It looks like they're discussing this problem because of a patch to 1.9.2.2, what version of Magento are you running now? Did you get there via a patch or a fresh install?

Comment: rwd and Magento 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option probably is to init the block variable with "false" on line 167[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why is this error getting generated? Is this a common issue?  I added `$block = false;` to `Filter.php. No errors yet. What does `$block = false;` do?