# Magento patch 7405 failing on v1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

I'm trying to wrap my head around why this magento patch keeps failing. Unfortunately due to the significance, I cant just ignore the patch as it's a serious security issue.

Essentially, I've run the patch `PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-42-03.sh` on my server and it keeps failing at

```
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 227.
```

My full output of the bash command

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 102.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 182 (offset -10 lines).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 (offset -3 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 264.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 118.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 121 (offset -12 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 227.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej
```

Note: There is no such file `lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej`

## What I have tried:

1. I have tried the advice of trying to install prior patches e.g. patch `PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46` onwards as suggested in other topics and I seem to get errors with this as well

   ```
   Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
   ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
   patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php.rej
   patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/View.php.rej
   patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej
   patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/messages.phtml.rej
   patching file get.php
   Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
   patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
   patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
   patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
   ```
2. Pretty much trying to apply every other patch and the only one that does install is `SUPEE-6482`, probably because previous ones are not installed.
3. Staring at my screen hoping that the problem would magically fix itself.
4. Crying in the corner

I was considering following [a tutorial](https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-7405-with-or-without-ssh/) where files could just be replaced, however seeing as the automated patcher doesn't work, I see that as being a slightly bad idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the following previous patches have been applied previously in the following order:

- SUPEE-5994
- SUPEE-6285
- SUPEE-6788
- SUPEE-7405

I've just test the order on on a clean version of 1.9.1.1 and it all runs successfully.

Comment: Gave it a shot, although SUPEE-5994 isn't installing in the first place. I'll debug it further although it hits an error of already modified on  `1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php.rej`

Comment: Do you have a file called `applied.patches.list` located in `app/etc`? If so this should display all the patches that have been applied to your magento install. Has 5994 been run previously?

Comment: Unfortunately not. No patches have been.

Comment: Is there any way for the downloader to be different without running a patch?

Comment: unless someone has modified it you could do a diff from here https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/1.9.1.1/ and see what is different

Comment: I took a look and the difference was http://i.imgur.com/4yUy5Nx.png on downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php . I saw that the change was in the 5994 patch, which someone else must have tried to do. In the applied.patches.list there isn't any 5994. Is it possible for the patch to change half the files and fail?

Comment: normally not no, when the patch fails it reverts all changes. Does the file exist in the  applied.patches.list? wondering if it doesn't actually say 5994 as the patch

Comment: I have a sneaky feeling the previous developer has tried manually patching off a source that was incorrect. Some files are patched, some are not by the looks. I think that I'll just go through and just try revert these changes to the source without breaking things.

Comment: There is nothing in the `applied.patches.list` unfortunately

Comment: Ah got ya, yeah that sounds like that would be the culprit.  Good Luck. Any issues let us know :)

Comment: After about 8 hours of sitting down and going through a significant amount of core files, I've finally managed to get the patches all 100% working. Most of the problems above were due to 5994 not being installed correctly to start with and `OnepageController.php` for some odd reason had an extra space on line 102 (According to the diff calculator) which I replaced with the file @ github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/1.9.1.1 and it's all fixed.

Comment: Ouch! Glad i could help @Matt

Comment: I have the same issue trying to install SUPEE-7405 on version 1.9.1.1. Previously installed patches are: `SUPEE-5998 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1`, `SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1`, `SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1`, `SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 (REVERTED)`, `SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v2`, `SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1` and `SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1`.  Before getting the error I patched `SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1` without any issues.  But SUPEE-7405 errors out.

Comment: With command `sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-42-03.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
`, It patches a lot of files up to this line, but errors out on the following: `patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php 
Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 194 (offset 2 lines).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php`.  And the rest patch

Comment: For your information, I have added `$block = false;` on line 175 to `Filter.php` file; since I was getting Error messages in the `system.log` regarding `Undefined variable: block in Filter.php`. This work around was suggested [here at stackexchange post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95394/error-message-in-system-log-regarding-undefined-variable-block-in-filter-php/96149#96149).  Of course the error went away after adding `$block = false;`!  But now I am getting the patch error? Any ideas?

Comment: @user2774042 you're better to ask a new question for this one. Are you able to do a diff or your filter.php and a clean version as the patch needs exact line numbers in order to patch so if you've added that line then the line numbers will be out and it will fail.

Comment: @rob3000.  Thanks for the reply.  Should I be deleting the comments I've made here?   I use WinMerge and there are differences!  I don't know whether the differences are from other applied patches ? The only change I made is the one i explained above.  Bad dilemma.  It might sound stupid, but should get a clean version, apply the patch and then add my revision?

Comment: @user2774042 from memory i think other patches do add items to the filter.php, are you able to remove the edit you did and try to rerun the patch and see if that works?

Comment: @rob3000. when I remove `$block = false;`,  it errors on `patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej`.  The differences between my existing Filter.php and the original file is on line 73 under **@var bool|string**  and **Setup callbacks for filters**.  And around line 171 **Retrieve Block html directive**.  Around line 470 **Store config directive**.  None of which where modified by me!  I guess it's time to create a new question?  Tks.

Comment: @rob3000.  Just wanted to add this also.  Under **Retrieve Block html directive** around line 171: Original file: `        if (isset($blockParameters['type'])) {
            $type = $blockParameters['type'];
            $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
        } elseif (isset($blockParameters['id'])) {
`

Comment: vs the existing file `        if (isset($blockParameters['type'])) {
            if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
                $type = $blockParameters['type'];
                $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
            }
        } elseif (isset($blockParameters['id'])) {
`.

Comment: @rob3000.  Per your recommendation,  I created a new question.  [Here is the link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101104/supee-7405-failing-to-install-on-my-version-of-1-9-1-1). I would appreciate if you would look at it. Thanks