# Install patch-7405 before patch 6788

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405

I have magento version 1.9.1.1, i have installed all previous patches except patch 6788, is it ok to install patch 7405 before 6788 or will it cause any issue..?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install patch 6788. The SUPEE-7405 patch will not install without that patch or any other patches not previously installed [Magento patch 7405 failing on v1.9.1.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99064/magento-patch-7405-failing-on-v1-9-1-1/99088#99088)